# Magento: Subtraction and Division on addAttributeToFilter

Tags: mysql, magento-1.7

I'm a newbie with Magento getResourceModel, and I'm trying to add a simple filter to my query, but i can't figure that using getResourceModel.

Original Query:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1)->setOrder('price', 'desc');
```

I just want add the where clause:

```
 (`price` - `final_price`) >= (`price` * 0.4)
```

Someone can help me to do this?

This is all, thanks!

Comment: Maybe that helps a bit: http://blog.onlinebizsoft.com/addattributetofilter-conditionals-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks feela, I had saw one blog post like that, and I visit the official magento doc. But I can't found how to do simple operations like division and subtraction.

Comment: I don't know if that is even possible using the `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` (which is the base class of any collections in Magento), but I guess that you need to modify the SELECT manually. `$collection->getSelect()` should return an instance of `Varien_Db_Select` – look into that class in `/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php`.

Comment: Thanks again @feeela! What I'm doing is right that. But, this query is the one who retrieves the product list to file:`../template/catalog/product/list.php` and the expected array than a manually select provides me, is different than the default.

Comment: I create a new list.php file, because this new will be shown on a new section, the promotion section. And I'm adapting this new file to work with a manually query. Thanks so much @feeela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally I found the correct way to do this, sorry to delay to post the answer here and thanks @feeela.

Looking the file `/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php` I found that exists the where function:

```
public function where($cond, $value = null, $type = null)
{
  $this->_parts[self::WHERE][] = $this->_where($cond, $value, $type, true);

  return $this;
}
```

So, what we need is just add a call to this function giving the condition that we want. In my case, I just add a condition to filter products that have 40% of discount.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1)
           ->addStoreFilter();
$collection->getSelect()->where( '(`price` - `final_price`) >= (`price` * 0.4)' );
```

So, I hope that this can be helpful for some dudes!

Grazie tutti!